# Is there a way to specify .NET Framework Version argument while using Install-Package in Nuget?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, asp.net-web-api

We are trying to install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` in a project that's targeting `.NET Framework 4.0`. Unfortunately the servers we are working on don't support .NET Framework 4.5.

When using Nuget `Package Manager Console` with the `Install-Package` command we are receiving the following error,

```
PM> install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.1.1'.
.
.
.
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

How do we choose the right .NET framework is there a command-line argument where we can mention the .NET version?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't select the .NET version, but you can select the version of the NuGet package:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version <package version>
```

So what you'd need to do is to figure out which version was the latest version that supported .NET 4.0. IIRC, it was [4.0.30506](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/4.0.30506).

So, to install version 4.0.30506, you use the command

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 4.0.30506
```

Some NuGet packages can contain builds for various different .NET versions (e.g. .NET 3.5, .NET 4, .NET 4.5, etc.), but ASP.NET Web API **2** only supports .NET 4.5.

ASP.NET Web API version 4.0.30506, on the other hand, corresponds to ASP.NET Web API **1**, and IIRC it runs on .NET 4.0.

Comment: It would be great if Nuget only shows the packages under 'Managed Nuget Packages' based on the framework we target. Anyways thanks for your help Mark!!!

Comment: I have created an issue for this: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Protocol/issues/22